# How to configure an IPv6 tunnel on AWS?

Tags: networking, ipv6, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I'm running openvpn on a dual-stack AWS EC2 instance (Ubuntu 18) in an AWS VPC.

Connecting to the VPN software and tunneling IPv6 seems to work fine; I can bring up a VPN link and ping6 around the VPN subnet with no problem.

Now I want to route an entire subnet over the VPN, and I can't get AWS to route packets to the instance.

My VPC is assigned 2600:1f18:6655:5c00::/56

My instance is in an AWS subnet ...:5c01::/64.

I want to route ...:5c02::/64 to the VPN.

1. `sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1` is set on the instance
2. source/dest address checking is disabled on both the instance and its interface
3. both the VPC's network ACL and the instance's security group allow all traffic
4. the VPC's main route table contains a /56 pointing to the instance's interface

I can ping6 from the instance out to the public Internet, no problem.

When I try to ping6 from an address on the VPN, tcpdump shows the requests being transmitted on the instance's AWS interface, but no replies come back.

I've tried adding ...:5c02::/64 as an AWS subnet and putting a route in the main route table directing that subnet to the instance, no effect.

Any idea what might be wrong?  Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but I'm starting to think that this is impossible.

AWS puts limits (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-eni.html#AvailableIpPerENI)) on the number of IP addresses (both v4 and v6) allowed per interface.

If you could route an entire subnet to an interface, it would be an easy way to defeat those limits.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and suffering (since I'm new to the subject), I managed to create something similar to what you mentioned (a dual-stack VPN (IPv6 + IPv4) using a IPv6 tunnel provided at tunnelbroker.net and following this tutorial:

https:// encomhat.com/2021/01/wireguard-he-tunnel/

There are other settings that need to be done on the AWS panel/instance, such as generating an IPv6 CIDR block for your server, allocating an IPv6 address for it, etc. I hope it helps a lot of people. I think this content below also can help out:

https://4sysops.com/archives/assign-an-ipv6-address-to-an-ec2-instance-dual-stack/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1164724)